# Listview images are misplacing

Tags: android

i'm having custom listview with text and image,the problem is first item image showing wrongly and remaining things are showing perfectly,and when ever 
i scroll the listview then first item image also showing perfect,can you please provide me some suggestion what i'm doing wrong

Here is my Asynctask

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Gropinion_Questions.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    try {
        pDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return Utils.getJSONString(params[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);


    if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
        showToast("No data found from web!!!");
        Gropinion_Questions.this.finish();
    } else {

        // get JSON result and give to JsonObject
        try {
            JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
            System.out.println("result........."+result);

            JSONArray    jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(ARRAY_NAME);

            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@ jsonArray @@@@@@@@@@@ "+jsonArray.length());

            Singleton.jsonArray = jsonArray;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                objItem = new QuestionsObject();

                objItem.setDbcsFacebookProfile(objJson.optString(dbcsFacebookProfile));

                objItem.setAvatar_img(objJson.optString(Avatar_image));

                objItem.setVotebar(objJson.optString(percentagenumber));

                objItem.setProfile_picture_value(objJson.optString(PROFILE_PIC_VALUE));

                objItem.setId(objJson.optString(ID));
                objItem.setTitle(objJson.optString(TITLE));
                objItem.setNick_name(objJson.optString(NICKNAME));
                objItem.setQues_type(objJson.optString(QUESTIONTYPE));
                objItem.setCategories(objJson.getString(CATEGORIES));
                objItem.setSubcatid(objJson.getString(SUBCATID));
                objItem.setTotal_vote(objJson.getString(TV));

                arrayOfList.add(objItem);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setAdapterToListview();

        if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            try {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                pDialog = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my adapter

```
public class QuestionRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QuestionsObject> {

private Activity activity;
private List<QuestionsObject> items;
private QuestionsObject objBean;
private int row;
final Context context = getContext();

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

public QuestionRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource,
        List<QuestionsObject> arrayList) {
    super(act, resource, arrayList);
    this.activity = act;
    this.row = resource;
    this.items = arrayList;

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    objBean = items.get(position);

    // converting dp in pixels

    holder.pic_image = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.question = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    holder.percentage_no = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.percentagenumber);
    holder.answer_img = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.answerimage);
    holder.voted = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    holder.voted_now = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    holder.bethefirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    holder.percentage_no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.answer_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.voted.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.voted_now.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.bethefirst.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Singleton.profile_picture_value = objBean.getProfile_picture_value();

    String dbcsFacebookProfile = objBean.getDbcsFacebookProfile();

    if (holder.pic_image != null) {

        if (Singleton.profile_picture_value.equals("1")) {

            String Avatarimageurl = avatarImagePic(objBean.getAvatar_img()
                    .toString());
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(Avatarimageurl, holder.pic_image);

        } else {
            // for facebook
            if (Singleton.login_channel.equals("1")) {

                System.out.println("default porfile pic"
                        + Singleton.profile_picture_value);

                imageLoader.DisplayImage(facebookimagepic(objBean
                        .getAvatar_img().toString()), holder.pic_image);

            }// end of facebook login if

            else {
                holder.pic_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_logooo); //
            }
        }
    }

    if (Singleton.profile_picture_value.equals("0")
            && dbcsFacebookProfile.equals("0")) {

        System.out.println("default porfile pic in else"
                + Singleton.profile_picture_value);

        holder.pic_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_logooo);
    }

    /*
     * if (holder.pic_image != null && null != objBean.getBitmap()) {
     * holder.pic_image.setImageBitmap(objBean.getBitmap()); }
     */

    if (holder.question != null && null != objBean.getTitle()
            && objBean.getTitle().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.question.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getTitle()));
    }
    if (holder.name != null && null != objBean.getNick_name()
            && objBean.getNick_name().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.name.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getNick_name()));
    }

    String totalVote = objBean.getTotal_vote();

    if (totalVote.equals("0")) {

        holder.percentage_no.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.answer_img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.voted.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.voted_now.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.bethefirst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.bethefirst.setText("Be the 1st\nto vote!");
    }// End if block
    else {

        String ques_Type = objBean.getQues_type();
        String newvoteBar = objBean.getVotebar();

        String[] newVoteArray = newvoteBar.split(",");

        if (ques_Type.equals("0")) {

            if (holder.percentage_no != null
                    && null != objBean.getVotebar()
                    && objBean.getVotebar().trim().length() > 0) {

                holder.percentage_no.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.answer_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.voted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.voted_now.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                String votePercente = newVoteArray[0]; // to store the vote
                                                        // percentage values

                int size = votePercente.length();

                String votedImageName = newVoteArray[1]; // to store the//
                                                            // images

                votedImageName.replaceAll("\\s", "");
                holder.percentage_no.setText(votePercente + "%");

                if (votedImageName.equals("Yes")
                        && holder.answer_img != null) {
                    holder.answer_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.yesimg);
                } else {
                    holder.answer_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimg);
                }
            }

        }// End if block question tye
        else {
            String votePercente = newVoteArray[0];
            try {
                String imageString = newVoteArray[2];

                imageString = imageString.replaceAll(" ", "");

                String AnswerImageurl = answerImage(imageString);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(AnswerImageurl, holder.answer_img);

                holder.percentage_no.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.answer_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.voted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.voted_now.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.percentage_no.setText(votePercente + "%");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// End else block Multi choice question
    }

    Animation animation = null;
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            R.anim.slidetop_tobottom);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    convertView.startAnimation(animation);
    animation = null;

    return convertView;
}

// get left hand side image based on the avatar

public String avatarImagePic(String pic) {

    String url = MainURL.address
            + "/app3/modules/boonex/photos/data/avatar_75_75/" + pic;
    return url;
}

// get right hand side image based on the product
public String answerImage(String img) {

    String url = MainURL.address
            + "/app3/modules/boonex/photos/data/thumb_75_75/" + img;
    return url;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView question, name;
    public ImageView pic_image, answer_img;
    public ProgressBar progressbar;
    public RatingBar rat;
    public TextView voted_now, percentage_no, voted, bethefirst;
}

public String facebookimagepic(String pic) {

    String url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + pic + "/picture?type=large";
    return url;
}

// get facebook profile pic based on the user id
public Bitmap fbimagepic(String pic) {
    Bitmap bit2 = null;
    try {
        URL feedImage2 = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + pic
                + "/picture?type=large");

        HttpURLConnection conn2 = (HttpURLConnection) feedImage2
                .openConnection();
        InputStream is2 = conn2.getInputStream();
        bit2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return bit2;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you loading images from web in adapter ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,No im loading images in background task and i'm just passing the values to the adapter class

Comment: then try to use external libraries like vollay or piccaso.

Comment: here i'm using lazy load approach,all are good except for the first row item